# Find distinct left cosets of $SL(2,\Bbb R)$ in $GL(2,\Bbb R)$

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Find distinct left cosets of $SL(2,\Bbb R)$ in $GL(2,\Bbb R)$.

I am guessing that it should be for $a \in \Bbb R$, $a \cdot SL(2,\Bbb R)$. Is this true?

Comment: yes that is correct. Given any  $A$ in $GL(2,R)$, $\frac{A}{det(A)}$ is in $SL(2,R)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that SL(2) is a normal subgroup of GL(2). It is the kernel of the homomorphism to the group of non-zero real numbers (under multiplication), given by the determinant function. $\phi\colon GL(2, \mathbf{R})\to\mathbf{R}^*,\  \phi(A)= \det(A)$ This homomorphism is surjective: given any real number one can find a matrix having that number as its determinant.   So the cosets are precisely the inverse images $\phi^{-1}(a)$ for $a\in\mathbf{R}^*$. So a coset is the same as the collection of matrices with fixed determinant.